# Fetching Firebase Records Based on Email

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch all the driveways which belongs to user using their email as the search key.

[image]

And here is the code I am writing:

```
  guard let currentUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser else {
            return
        }

        let query = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath :"driveways").queryEqual(toValue: currentUser.email!, childKey: "email")

        query.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
        })
```

How can I get all the driveways based on user's email address?

Comment: Remember to always post your firebase structure as text, no images. That way they are searchable and we an copy/paste into an answer if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (Swift 3 Firebase 3)

```
let email = "johndoe@gmail.com"
let queryRef = drivewaysRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "email")
                           .queryEqual(toValue: email)
queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for snap in snapshot.children {
        let driveSnap = snap as! FIRDataSnapshot
        let driveDict = driveSnap.value as! [String:AnyObject] //driveway child data
        let city = driveDict["city"] as! String
        let state = driveDict["state"] as! String
        print("email: \(email)  city: \(city)  state: \(state)")
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working. But how it is able to find "email" child. Because the immediate descendent of the drivewaysRef is "kbIFi0" (autochildID). Can you explain this?

Comment: I guess when I say drivewaysRef I am actually pointing to all the root child elements. That is how it is able to find the associated property email with a particular value.

Comment: @johndoe Firebase queries the children contained in the specified ref, 'looking into' each child ref for the orderedBy node. If the answer helped, don't forget to accept it!